# Fixed point of compact operator in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, compact-operators

Let $M:=\overline{B(o,1)} $ be a closed unit ball of Banach space X. Assume that $F: M \rightarrow X$ is a nonlinear compact operator and 
$F(\partial M)  \subset M$.

Then F has a fixed point in M.

What is the intuition behind this ? Does it follows directly from Schauder Fixed Point Theorem? Its far from being obvious to me.

Thanks